# Discord.PY цикл блокирует код

Tags: discord

Не могу понять, почему цикл в background_task_cenniky вешает весь код и ничего не выполняется.
Прошу помощи. Я новичок в python, поэтому прошу развернутый ответ.

```
# Библиотеки
import time                                # для работы со временем
import datetime                            # для работы со временем
import discord                             # DiscordAPI
import asyncio                             # библиотека асинхронного кода
from discord.ext import commands, tasks    # импортируем работу с командами
from discord.ext.tasks import loop         # функция цикла
from config import settings                # забираем данные настроек из config.py

#                                                               ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ

# Для работы с DiscordAPI
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
# Чтобы получить текущее время
now = datetime.datetime.now()

#                                                                СОБЫТИЯ

# Эвент о запуске бота и подключению в DiscordAPI
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Time',datetime.datetime.now(), '\nScript connected to {}'.format(bot.user))
  # Указываем ID канала, куда отправить сообщение
    channel = bot.get_channel(*********)
  # Отправляем сообщение
    await channel.send('бот зашел в сеть')
  # Устанавливаем статус бота
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game("GarwinVRN"))

# Кто-то присоединился к серверу
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Привет, если ты наш сотрудник, мы подтвердим твою учетку')
    for ch in bot.get_guild(member.guild.id).channels:
            if ch.name == 'для-входа':
                    await bot.get_channel(ch.id).send(f'{member}, у нас новый запрос')

# Кто-то вышел с сервера
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    for ch in bot.get_guild(member.guild.id).channels:
            if ch.name == 'болталка':
                    await bot.get_channel(ch.id).send(f'{member}, вышел из группы')

# Уведомление печать ценников
async def background_task_cenniky():  
    while True:
        z = time.localtime()  
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if z.tm_hour == 8  and z.tm_min == 25  and z.tm_sec == 0:
            print("TEST TIMER MESSAGE")
            channel = bot.get_channel(************)
            channel.send('background_task')


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(background_task_cenniky())

    await asyncio.gather(task1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        asyncio.run(main())
#                                                              КОМАНДЫ  

# Команда пинг
@bot.command()          # Говорим что будем обрабатывать команду
async def пинг(ctx): # Создаём функцию и ставим перехватчик ctx.
    author = ctx.message.author # Объявляем переменную author и записываем туда информацию об авторе.
    await ctx.reply(f'**Да тут я, тут, {author.mention}! Че пристал?**') # Выводим сообщение с упоминанием автора, обращаясь к переменной author.

# Команда инфо
@bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx, arg=None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if arg == None:
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} \n**Введи:**\n!инфо создатель\n!инфо команды')
    elif arg == 'создатель':
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} \n**Мой создатель Алексей Шнайдер aka SNR93**')
    elif arg == 'команды':
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} \n**Список моих команд**:\n!пинг - проверить, в сети и работает ли бот')
    else:
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} **Нет такой команды. Список команд: !инфо команды**')



#                                                     СТАРТ 
bot.run(settings['token']) # Обращаемся к словарю settings с ключом token, для получения токена
```

Comment: выхода из функций нет, получается бесконечный цикл

Comment: ну так он и должен быть бесконечным, т.к. уведомление должно приходить каждый день в одно и тоже время. Или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Во первых перенесите bot.run() внутрь main() а то он далеко и сразу не ясно в какой момент он должен выполниться. А после этого сразу будет видно, что вы выполняете `await asyncio.gather(task1)` и только после этого выполняете bot.run(). await не окончиться пока задача не завершиться, а она не завершиться ни когда, так как бесконечная, вот до bot.run() управление и не доходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл блокирует весь код, который выполняется в данном потоке. Для подобных случаев в модуле `asyncio` предусмотрена функция `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(function(*args), loop)`, принимающая на вход первым аргументом **вызов** функции с передачей аргументов (если нужно), а вторым - поток, в котором нужно выполнить эту функцию. При этом работоспособность потока сохранится для остальных действий.

---

**Простой пример.** Вам нужно отправлять какой-либо текст в определенный канал раз в 10 секунд.

Для начала создадим функцию отправки сообщений. Назовем ее `send_info(channel)` - она будет принимать один аргумент - канал для отправки сообщений.

```py
import discord
import asyncio

async def send_info(channel: discord.TextChannel):
    while True:
        await channel.send('Информация')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Теперь создадим обработчик события `on_ready()`, таким образом убедившись, что бот запущен и запустим функцию отправки сообщений:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    info_channel = bot.get_channel(760471276072390836)
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_info(info_channel), bot.loop)
```

**Готово!** Теперь бот будет параллельно выполнять еще и свои основные функции по обработке других событий.

---

Но, стоит также обратить внимание на еще один способ, который уже предоставляет библиотека `discord-py`.

[**`discord.ext.tasks`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers) позволяет пометить декоратором функцию, которая должна повторяться несколько раз. В этом случае реализация будет немного другой:

Опять же импортируем модуль, и создаем функцию. Выставлять задержку в 10 сек. уже не надо, т.к. она теперь указана в декораторе:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def send_info(channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.send('Информация')
```

Ну и точно также запускаем функцию, когда бот будет готов:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    info_channel = bot.get_channel(760470076070690836)
    send_info.start(info_channel)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разъяснение! Ваш совет действительно помог и теперь все работает, как нужно!