# Не получается сделать цикл смены названия канала discord.py

Tags: python, requests, discord, discord.py, async-await

Я хочу сделать так, что бы со стороннего сайта бралась информация и изменялась под названия канала каждые 5 минут. Но я не могу сделать цикл асинхронной функции, перепробовал уже всё.

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Все циклы запущены.')
    while True:
        site = requests.get('https://www.gs4u.net/ru/s/99415.html').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, 'lxml')
        server_2 = str(str(soup.find('div', class_='text'))[54:-11]).split('<')[0]
        site = requests.get('https://www.gs4u.net/ru/s/99414.html').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, 'lxml')
        server_1 = str(str(soup.find('div', class_='text'))[54:-11]).split('<')[0]
        await bot.get_channel(957661666722578472).edit(name=f'Онлайн №1: {server_1}')
        await bot.get_channel(957663447535980675).edit(name=f'Онлайн №2: {server_2}')
```

Comment: Попробуйте через таски

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1390305/discord-py-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1390328#1390328